# Solving the radial part of Poisson's equation via power series method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, harmonic-functions, poissons-equation

We're solving Poisson's equation in Electrodynamics, and one ODE we must solve is: $$\dfrac{d^2 R}{dr^2}+\dfrac{2}{r}\dfrac{dR}{dr}-\dfrac{l(l+1)}{r^2}R=0$$ where $l\in\mathbb{R}$. I already know that the solution is in the form $R=Ar^l+\dfrac{B}{r^{l+1}}$ but I want to solve it via power series (instead of the miracle Ansatz). I assumed that the solution takes the form: $$R=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ir^i$$ such that when I plug this in the ODE I get:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left[i(i-1)+a_i+2ia_i-l(l+1) \right]r^{i-2}=0$$
and so $$a_i=\dfrac{l(l+1)}{i(i+1)}$$
My solution is then $$R=l(l+1)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{r^i}{i(i+1)}=l(l+1)\left[\dfrac{1}{2}r+\dfrac{1}{6}r^2+\dfrac{1}{12}r^3+\dfrac{1}{20}r^4+\dots \right]$$
This solution doesn't seem to match with the actual solution. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your third equation. The result of plugging your guess into the original ode gives you

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_i a_i\left[i(i-1) +2i -l(l+1) \right]r^{i-2} = 0
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:)**

For differential equation
$$\dfrac{d^2 R}{dr^2}+\dfrac{2}{r}\dfrac{dR}{dr}-\dfrac{\ell(\ell+1)}{r^2}R=0$$
we see $p(x)=\dfrac{2}{r}$ and $q(x)=-\dfrac{\ell(\ell+1)}{r^2}$ (comparison with $y''+p(r)y'+q(r)y=0$) which show $r=0$ is regular point of this equation, then 
$$p_0=\lim_{r\to0}rp(r)=2~~~,~~~q_0=\lim_{r\to0}r^2q(r)=-\ell(\ell+1)$$
so the Ferobenius characteristic equation $\lambda(\lambda+1)+p_0\lambda+q_0=0$ is 
$$\lambda(\lambda+1)+2\lambda-\ell(\ell+1)=0$$
hence $\lambda=\ell$ and $\lambda=-\ell-1$, and two answers must be of the form
$$R=x^\ell\sum_{r=0}^\infty a_nr^2~~~~~,~~~~~R=x^{-\ell-1}\sum_{r=0}^\infty a_nr^2$$
so you must consider these series as solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's put the equation in the form
$$
r^2R''(r)+r R'(r)-l(l+1)R(r)=0\tag 1
$$
We look for a series solution of the form ([Frobenius Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method))
$$
R(r)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nr^{n+s}\tag 2
$$
Substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$ we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+s)(n+s-1)a_nr^{n+s}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+s)a_nr^{n+s}-l(l+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nr^{n+s}=0\tag 3
$$
We then re-order the sums to contain the same power of $r$.   We find the indicial equation by setting $n=0$ in all the sums of $(3)$ that bear the lowest exponent of $r$.  Since all the sums in $(3)$ are to the same power of $r$ (i.e, 
$r^{n+s}$), all the sums contribute to the indicial equation and we obtain for $a_0\ne 0$: 
$$
s(s-1)+2s-l(l+1)=0\tag 4
$$
and solving $(4)$ we find
$$
s=l\quad\text{and}\quad s=-(l+1)\tag 5
$$
We next find the recursion relation.  Note that  since all the sums already involve the same exponent of $r$, there is no need to do any re-indexing.  That means that all the coefficients will remain expressed as $a_n$, and so we can write immediately: 
$$
\Big[(n+s)(n+s-1)+2(n+s)-l(l+1)\Big]a_n=0\tag 6
$$
Equation $(6)$ tells us that either the bracketed  expression vanishes or the value of $a_n$ vanishes. We know that the bracketed expression vanishes for $n=0$.  However, for any other value of $n$, the bracketed expression cannot vanish, meaning that $a_n = 0$ for all values of $n > 0$.  This means the only term in the series expansion is the $a_0$ term, so our solution for equation $(1)$ becomes simply:

> $$
> R(r)=Ar^l+Br^{-(l+1)}
> $$

Comment: How do we know for all values $n>0$, the bracketed term cannot vanish?

Comment: The solutions must be linearly independents.

Comment: I'm still struggling to see why we can not just say $a_n$ is zero for $n>0$.

Comment: Actually you can say it because for $n>0$ the solutions are linearly independents if $a_n=0$.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that I don't understand what you exactly mean by linearly independent. I don't see how this guarantees $a_n=0$.